# Custom error style in cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp

i want to show the login errors in red color with a small icon before it, I mean by errors the validation message just like:

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
    'rule'       => 'email',
    'required'   => true,
    'message'   => 'Please enter your email adress'
)
)
```

i've read that these following lines in css will do it , but acutally it didn't work with me , any ideas ?

```
.error-message {
    background:url( path/to/img.png ) no-repeat top left;
    padding-left:40px; /* or whatever you need for the image to fit */   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following

div.error-message Instead of  .error-message

So use

```
div.error-message {
    background:url( path/to/img.png ) no-repeat top left;
    padding-left:40px; /* or whatever you need for the image to fit */   
}
```

Also

```
    ' 'rule'       => 'email',`
```

Is for HTML5 client side validation .So you cant modify it , But you can use serverside validation using cutsom made rule.

Answer (score 1):

I think that validation error and setFlash message have id="authMessage" and class="message". Try to inspect the element of validation message in your browser, so you can see what id or class it use.

I hope that it helps you. :)

Comment: thanks i totally forgot about inspecting the element in browser.
the class is : error-message  , why it doesn't work  :/  ?

  `<div class="error-message">Please enter your email</div>`